# How to chkdsk completely unattended

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, chkdsk, cmd.exe, windows-task-scheduler

have a question about scheduling chkdsk: I'm running chkdsk on task scheduler in windows 7 for my main hardrive (where windows is installed) using the following
command: echo y|chkdsk /f /r.

But I can't use the same command for my second hard drive, as chkdsk first asks me if I want to force dismount it, which I don't, so I can't echo y...

I need to answer n for the first question and y for the second.

Anyone know how I can formulate a command that answers n and y to chkdsk prompts?

Or...

Is there a way to schedule chkdsk without it asking you anything?

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, but adding "/x" to chkdsk cmd makes chkdsk only ask if I want to schedule the task, making echo y valid.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you could specify the drive parameter for each chkdsk

```
echo n|chkdsk /r C:
echo y|chkdsk /r D:
```